# undefined method error '-' while trying to update user balance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `user.rb` file

```
has_many :virtual_transactions

def balance
  bought_transactions = VirtualTransaction.where(buyer_id: self.id)
  sold_transactions = VirtualTransaction.where(seller_id: self.id)
  bought_amount = bought_transactions.inject{|sum, t| sum + t.amount}
  sold_amount = sold_transactions.inject{|sum, t| sum + t.amount}
  bought_amount - sold_amount
end
```

in my `virtual_transaction.rb`

```
belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'buyer_id'
belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'seller_id'

def amount
  quantity.to_f * stock_price.to_f 
end
```

I am trying to update a buyer's and seller's balance independently without the use of a `balance` column. However, I get

> undefined method error '-' for VirtualTransaction

when I try something like:

```
User.first.balance
```

The idea is to update buyer's balance and seller's balance separately. (increment for seller, decrement for buyer)

Comment: You don't have any `bought_transactions`, hence no `bought_amount`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do `bought_amount - sold_amount` you need to convert the `bought_amount` from the class `VirtualTransaction` to the [integer class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html) with something like `bought_amount.to_i`

```
def balance
bought_transactions = VirtualTransaction.where(buyer_id: self.id)
sold_transactions = VirtualTransaction.where(seller_id: self.id)
bought_amount = bought_transactions.inject{|sum, t| sum + t.amount}
sold_amount = sold_transactions.inject{|sum, t| sum + t.amount}
bought_amount.to_i - sold_amount.to_i
end
```

Still I do not have any idea of what your `VirtualTransaction` model looks like, but you should translate it to integer before trying to do that calculation

---

UPDATE

@Solias with the `def amount` method you convert your `quantity` and `stock_price` to `float` https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html you are using that method bought on the `sold_amount` and `bought_amount`, so those two fields should be `float` and that class has the `-` method. now you say me that this values are undefined variables. So, your error is being triggered because an `undefined variable` does not have the method `-` that a float data type has.

So the problem is hear in this two lines that return an undefined nil variable

```
bought_amount = bought_transactions.inject{|sum, t| sum + t.amount}
sold_amount = sold_transactions.inject{|sum, t| sum + t.amount}
```

You need to find a way to correctly calculate `bought_amount` and `sold_amount`, keep in mind that a sum of float number should be a float, so you can use [this methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html) to do the calculations

The problem hear is that

```
bought_amount = nil or undefined
sold_amount = nil or undefined
```

so

```
- sold_amount
```

does not exist, because the nil class does not have `-` method

I need to go. good luck

Comment: there's nothing in my virtual_transaction.rb file except the amount method, some validations and the association. when I try `bought_amount.to_i - sold_amount.to_i I get a "to_i" method undefined.

Comment: @Solias what is the `data type` of `bought_amount`?

Comment: @Solias when you do `sold_amount` in the console what is the output? `inject` is part of the enumerable class but may be included also in other classes

Comment: I get an "undefined method or variable"

Comment: @Solias I updated my question, check the `updated` section, this should be enought for you to write your code